# Elementary OS doesn't recognize my partitions

Tags: dual-boot, grub, elementary-website, microsoft-windows

**I know this question has been asked like a million times, but I am yet to find an answer.**

I have Windows 7, though my computer itself came with Ubuntu(Dell). I didn't have much experience in it, so I preferred windows 8 and now I'm on windows 7 again.

**I tried Installing Elementary OS, and it didn't recognize my partitions, instead it took my entire 500GB disk as empty**

Here is a screenShot [image]

And Another

[image]

**However, the file explorer(Or whatever they call it in Linux), shows My Partitions**

Also, the other questions had answers as links, If you do that please give me adequate steps, for I have to admit **I am a novice in Linux**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the Answer Myself.

**All I had to do was delete some partition(In windows) and provide the setup some un-allocated space**

After Doing that, the problem was solved.

Thanks To Everyone, Anyway!

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for your partitions???

NTFS?

EXT 2, 3 or 4?

JFS?

XFS?

ReiserFS?

Also, what is your install?   Is it UEFI?    Also, your sentence is confusing as heck.   Are you trying to say:

1) my computer came with Ubuntu originally

2) I installed Windows 8.

3)  Didn't like Windows 8, so deleted it and installed Windows 7.

???????????????????????????????

Do this test: grab/download another Linux OS, and see if its installer recognizes your current partitions.  *Hint:  download debian live 8.5 or fedora 24/centOS 7, put it on a USB (via dd command), and see if they recognize your partitions as they actually now exist.  Heck, this test may be even better: download and put the latest Gparted Live on a CD (or USB), fire it up, and see if it recognizes the partitions on that hard drive*.   Elementary Loki's installer is the one used by a lot of Linux distros.  If it is not seeing your partitions, I am not optimistic.   And if Gaprted Live cannot see those partitions, well, then, from what I and a few others have seen, your only recourse is going to be dd-ing that whole drive.   Or, you could, like mentioned above, just stick to what's on it right now.  Windows and Ubuntu??...meh, wipe that crapper-stuff off for good and make that HD sing with Loki or Debian or Fedora or....... ;-)